# How to loop .animate JQuery

Tags: jquery, animation

I am working with a single div with an image inside. I need the animation to scroll from right-left of the page and then comeback to the right and continue in a loop. I have looked over many posts on here but am not able to get the script working properly.

```
'$(document).ready(function(){
    function loop() {

       $('#clouds').animate({left: '+=1400',},50000, 'linear', function(){
           loop();
       });
```

HTML

```
< div id="clouds">< img border="0" alt="animated clouds" src="/images/clouds.png" />< /div>
```

CSS

```
#clouds {
    position:absolute;
    z-index:500;
    right:0px;
    top:10px;
}
```

Comment: is the `'` at the beginning of your jQuery intentional?

Comment: No it was not. I am working on a content management system that isn't exactly eye candy. However, without the added ' it still isn't functioning properly.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try this:

**JSFiddle** http://jsfiddle.net/2YqH2/

You're not moving the clouds back to the right side. Inside the loop function, I added

```
$('#clouds').css({right:0});
```

and the loop will continue from there. I also changed your animation to animate the "right" property since you said you wanted the clouds to move from right to left.

Also, your javascript was not well-formed. Make sure you get those closing braces and parentheses! Here's the fixed javascript.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function loop() {
        $('#clouds').css({right:0});
        $('#clouds').animate ({
            right: '+=1400',
        }, 5000, 'linear', function() {
            loop();
        });
    }
    loop();
});
```

Comment: I appreciate this dearly! I am at an internship and have come to stackoverflow for many questions that are usually answered already. I didn't expect such great response time and kindness to a noob like myself. One last question pertaining I have read that 'linear' cuts down the choppy movement but is there another way as well? I bumped it up to 50000 but is still rough.

Comment: If you could post an example with multiple divs would be great as well. Thanks ahead of time I greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 4):

All the above answers are somewhat 'hack' solutions.

According to the [jQuery documentation for `animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/), the second paramter is an `options` object which has a parameter `complete`; a function that is called when the animation completes.

In OP's case, this `option` object would be configured as follows:

```
function loop() {
    $('#clouds').css({right:0});
    $('#clouds').animate({
        right: '+=1400',
    }, {
        duration: 5000, 
        easing: 'linear', 
        complete: loop
    });
}
loop();
```

Answer (score 2):

Just to add some info to others, if you're not going to use `animate()` you should use some `setTimeout()` to prevent the error **`Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`**

Example(**Using jQuery**):

**.js**

```
function looping() {
    $('.loader').fadeOut(1000);
    $('.loader').fadeIn(1000);
    setTimeout(function(){
        looping();
    }, 10);
}
```

**.html**

```
<div class='loader'>Loading...</div>
```

Comment: No need to create function **nesting**. Just invoke timeout like this:   `setTimeout(looping, 10)`

Answer (score 0):

JAVASCRIPT:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#clouds').click(function() {
loop();       
    });

function loop(){
    alert('a');
        $('#clouds').animate({
            opacity: 0.25,
            left: '+=1400',
            height: 'toggle'
        }, 5000, 'linear', function() {
            loop();
        });

}

});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="clouds"><img border="0" alt="animated clouds" src="../img/image.png" /></div>
```

your error is that you are not calling the function loop never.  look how [it works,](http://jsfiddle.net/RYybh/) you can remove the `alert('a')` because it's just a flag to know that the cycle start over. now you need to make the reverse movement (like reset the div, to start over the movement cycle).

Comment: I am working on a content management system at work and JQuery is imported. I tried the above script and still have no movement. I also tried calling the function again where // Animation complete is but had no luck.

Comment: Can you use firebug and tell us the javascript error message?

Comment: I am currently trying to swap the first #cloud div with another #cloud2 div.