# Loop/Repeat jQuery animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation

I have a button on click of which a fish appears and it should randomly over a container at random places. but in my code its just animating only once and not repeating overand overagain. I want my function to be generic so that it can be run over and over of many fishes and be efficient code.

The HTML:

```
  <input type="button" value="Post" class="post-button" />
```

The jQuery:

```
var idgenerated=0;
$('.post-button').on('click',function(e){
    //$('#container img:last-child').append('<div class="small-fish"> </div>');
    $('#rightarrow').after('<div class="fishhatch" id="'+idgenerated+'"></div>');
    $('.pop-up-selectCategory').hide(); 
    $('.oyster').removeClass('oyster-click');
    animatenewfish(idgenerated);
    idgenerated++;  
}); 

function animatenewfish(idgenerated) {
    console.log("hi");
    var Fishv1 = $("#"+idgenerated),
    theContainer = $("#container"),
    maxLeft = theContainer.width() - Fishv1.width()-100,
    maxTop = theContainer.height() - Fishv1.height()-100,
    leftPos = Math.floor(Math.random() * maxLeft),
    topPos = Math.floor(Math.random() * maxTop),
    imgRight = "Assets/R1gif.gif",
    imgLeft = "Assets/FIsh1.gif";
    console.log(maxLeft+"max");
    console.log(leftPos+"travel");
    if (Fishv1.position().left < leftPos) {
        Fishv1.css("background-image",'url("' + imgRight + '")');
    } else {
        Fishv1.css("background-image",'url("' + imgLeft + '")');    
    }

    Fishv1.animate({
        "left": leftPos,
        "top": topPos
    }, 18000, animatenewfish);
}
```

Comment: http://www.jquerybyexample.net/2012/02/how-to-use-jquery-settimeout-function.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11401535/how-to-loop-animate-jquery

Answer (score 0):

put your animation in

```
setInterval(function(){
    Fishv1.animate({
        "left": leftPos,
        "top": topPos
    }, 18000, animatenewfish(idgenerated));
},18000);
```

so it will be called after each `18000` milliseconds.

Comment: As i can see OP is calling  `animatenewfish(idgenerated);` function on click.

Answer (score 0):

change code Where you are calling your function 
This code will call function every `500` ms.

```
  /*Jquery Code*/
  var idgenerated=0;
  $('.post-button').on('click',function(e){

    //$('#container img:last-child').append('<div class="small-fish"> </div>');
    $('#rightarrow').after('<div class="fishhatch" id="'+idgenerated+'"></div>');
    $('.pop-up-selectCategory').hide(); 
    $('.oyster').removeClass('oyster-click');
    setInterval(function() { animatenewfish(idgenerated); }, 500);        
    idgenerated++;

});
```

Answer (score 0):

The animate takes an optional callback

```
Fishv1.animate({
    "left": leftPos,
    "top": topPos
}, 18000, animatenewfish(idgenerated));
```

[How can I loop an animation continuously in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6767286/jquery-continuously-loop-animation?answertab=votes#tab-top)